# GoLang (server) + CPP global reference JNI calling multiple times/multiple methods

Tags: c++, go, java-native-interface, cgo

I'm trying to use a Java Library in GoLang using CGO and JNI.

**Java Library**

It has 2 methods.

- Init Library (Ex. make API call and cache the API response (it does complex cache which will take months and months to build in GO))
- Search method to search cache and return expected response.

```
public static void initCache(String url, String ttl) throws Exception {
    try {
        //init cache
        // I also tried to attach thread to keep the process live with while(true) { Thread.sleep(10000);} and it was printing message constantly
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static String search(String txt, String id) throws Exception {
    try {
        return txt; //Literarily that's all I have at this method.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**GoLang (Cgin Http server)**

- On app startup, I call Init Library method
- On request I call search method. (FAILING WITH SEGMENTATION ERROR)

**CPP Bridge**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <jni.h>

#include "librarycache.hpp"

JNIEnv *javaEnv;
jclass libraryClass_g;

void initLibrary()
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=onebigjarfile";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&javaEnv, &vm_args);
    delete options;
    if (rc != JNI_OK)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    jclass libraryClass = javaEnv->FindClass("com/cache/boo/CacheManager");
    
    libraryClass_g = (jclass)javaEnv->NewGlobalRef(libraryClass);
    javaEnv->DeleteLocalRef(libraryClass);
    

    jmethodID initCacheMid = javaEnv->GetStaticMethodID(libraryClass_g, "initCache", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    
    jstring jstr1 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("http://urltoapi");
    jstring jstr2 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("60000");
    javaEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(libraryClass_g, initCacheMid, jstr1, jstr2);
    jmethodID searchFunction = javaEnv->GetStaticMethodID(libraryClass_g, "search", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"); // Works fine no errors
    jstring jstr3 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("Pasu");
    jstring jstr4 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("Pathi");
    javaEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(libraryClass_g, searchFunction, jstr3, jstr4);
    std::cout << "Library initialized" << std::endl;
   
}

void search()
{
    try
    {

        jstring jstr3 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("Pasu");
        jstring jstr4 = javaEnv->NewStringUTF("Pathi");
        
        jmethodID searchFunction = javaEnv->GetStaticMethodID(libraryClass_g, "search", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"); // SEGMENTATION FATAL ERROR
        std::cout << "searchFunction success>>>>" << std::endl;
        // javaEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(libraryClass_g, searchFunction, jstr3, jstr4);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect of "JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&javaEnv, &vm_args);" initializing "javaEnv" correctly.

Comment: @Ripi2 It is exactly as per https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html let me know if any adjustment required. I'll try it out.

Comment: Please run your code under a debugger and add a stack trace instead of making us guess at which line it crashes. Also try the `-Xcheck:jni` JVM option. Random guess: the OS thread calling `search` is different from the one calling `initLibrary` and you did not attach the calling thread to the JVM.